# How to remove few characters in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

So, how can I remove 7 or 6 characters in VB.net?
For example, I have this text in vb.net

```
Sherlock Holmes || tvn
Arsene Lupin || tf
```

I want to save the data to database, but only the name, like this

```
Sherlock Holmes
Arsene Lupin
```

I have tried this

`txtBox.Text.ToString.TrimEnd(" ", "|", "t", "v", "n")`

but the result always give me like this

```
Sherlock Holmes
Arsene Lupi
```

The `n` from `Lupin` is also missing.

So, How can I remove the characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this time you can use [`.SubString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) along with [`.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) So the snippet will be like this:

```
Dim input= "Sherlock Holmes || tvn"
Console.WriteLine("First output : {0}",input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("||")))
```

Here is [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ycqL6F)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function, which returns an array of string that become separated when removing a delimiter.  Then you could just grab the first element in that array that is returned.  For example:

```
txtBox.Text.ToString.Replace(" || ", "#").Split("#")(0)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it's only show the first word. `Sherlock` and `Arsene` :(

Comment: You are right, I updated my testcase and I have arrived at this solution.  How does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, this is work, but why we must replace `||` to `#` first then `split` it? Isn't it should be the same as before?? I'm sorry I'm just not really understand.

Comment: @JTR || are 2 characters thats why

Answer (score 0):

You may use this,

```
Dim Str1 AS STRING = "" 
Dim Str2 AS STRING = "" 

Str1 = TextBox.Text 'Holds your textboxName 

for i = 0 to Str1.length-1

    IF (STR1(i) = "|")
        Exit for
    END IF
STR2 = STR2 + Str1(i) 'Your new textbox name
next
'Now use STR2
```

Comment: This will still include a space after the name though, you should trim the String after the loop.